# aspx and jquery.ajax is always returning an error

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webmethod

This code worked fine in mvc2, but moving back to traditional ASPX (because of Sharepoint 2010). I am encountering errors. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong for this framework?

This ajax call is in the $.ready

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'siteName=a&siteUrl=b',
        url: 'Wizard.aspx/DoesNameUrlExist',
        beforeSend: function () { alert("before send"); },
        complete: function () { alert("complete"); },
        success: function (data) { alert("success"); },
        error: function (data) {
            if ($("meta[name=debug]").attr("content") == "true") {
                //Full Error when debugging
                var errDoc = window.open();
                errDoc.document.write(data.responseText);
                errDoc.document.close();
            }
            else {
                // generic error message for production use
                alert("An unexpected error occurred.");
            } return false;
        }
    });
```

code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string DoesNameUrlExist(string siteName, string siteUrl)
{
    //do something
    return someString;
}
```

I get an error everytime.

Comment: Do you know what the error message is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send JSON to the service and indicate that you're doing so via the `contentType` header:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '{"siteName":"a","siteUrl":"b"}',
    url: 'Wizard.aspx/DoesNameUrlExist',
    beforeSend: function () { alert("before send"); },
    complete: function () { alert("complete"); },
    success: function (data) { alert("success"); },
    error: function (data) {
        if ($("meta[name=debug]").attr("content") == "true") {
            //Full Error when debugging
            var errDoc = window.open();
            errDoc.document.write(data.responseText);
            errDoc.document.close();
        }
        else {
            // generic error message for production use
            alert("An unexpected error occurred.");
        } return false;
    }
});
```

More info here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Also, if you're using jQuery 1.4, you can drop the `dataType`.  [jQuery will infer JSON automatically based on the response's Content-Type header](http://encosia.com/save-yourself-some-typing-when-you-call-asp-net-services/).

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls in jQuery will always give you an error if you declare your `contentType` as json and the response content type is anything but json. If the response from your WebMethod has something different (such as html or text), you'll always get that error. You can set that response type on your method like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string DoesNameUrlExist(string siteName, string siteUrl)
```

Outside of WebMethods this can also be achieved like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: Since he's calling a page method, it does expect JSON for the input parameters, and it also does automatically set the `application/json` Content-Type on the response.  No need to do that manually.

Comment: i thought is only expected json as input if you specified it.  [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  we have used pageMethods in the past and have not passed in json

Comment: You may have gotten away with that if there were no parameters, but you must use JSON input parameters with static "page methods" and ASMX "ScriptServices".  You may not have noticed that in the past if you were using a ScriptManager to call page methods via the PageMethod.YourMethodName() syntax.  MicrosoftAjax.js handles the client-side JSON serialization automatically in that case.

Comment: ok, so what is the best way when you fire an ajax call to decifer whether it is a normal page submit post back or an ajax call?  Seems like my ajax calls and form submits are posting back.  Which i understand the form submission should be, but i didn't think the ajax call would end up in the Page_Load event.  any code examples?  My code never hits the WebMethods automatically.  Are you required to have a scriptmanager on the aspx page?

Comment: @Anthony: A call to a page method would end up in your Page_Load event if you don't use a POST request with Content-Type application/json, because it won't hit the page method otherwise.  You do not need a ScriptManager. Have you tried the code in my answer yet? That's the approach you must take in order to invoke page methods via jQuery.

Comment: @ Dave: yes i have, problem is that it goes into the Page_Load event and that is it.  it does not go into the WebMethod after hitting the Page_Load event